# HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error MediaType.APPLICATION_XML in Maven Dependencies

Tags: java, rest, maven, http, jersey

Actually , I'm struggling with this issue from two days . I am not able to output in console and I do not know what the problem is?

I am hitting this URL on my local machine, http://localhost:8080/Last/webapi/employee/p2

Below is the Screenshot of my issue :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vubwA.png

Code is as below.

pom.xml

```
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.webservices</groupId>
    <artifactId>Last</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Last</name>

    <build>
        <finalName>Last</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            
            <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
            <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
        </dependency>
        
<!-- Thanks for using https://jar-download.com -->
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-binding</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.media/jersey-media-jaxb -->


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-bundle -->

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.19.4</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.media/jersey-media-jaxb -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-jaxb</artifactId>
    <version>2.31</version>
</dependency>




    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.31</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container,
     see implementation details http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html -->
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  
  </welcome-file-list>
  
   <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.webservices.Last</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

EmployeesList.java

```
package com.webservices.Last;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.Media;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.GenericEntity;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path(value = "employee")
public class EmployeesList {

    List<StaffInformation> st = null;
    public EmployeesList() {
        st = new ArrayList<>();
        st.add(new StaffInformation("Kerem", "Kağan","123"));
        st.add(new StaffInformation("Java", "Oracle","321"));
    }
    
    
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    @Path("/p2")
    public Response listXML()
    {
        List<StaffInformation> list = new ArrayList<StaffInformation>();
        list.add(new StaffInformation("kerem", "ss", "123"));
        GenericEntity<List<StaffInformation>> entity = new GenericEntity<List<StaffInformation>>(list) {};
        
        Response response = Response.ok(entity).build();
        return response;
    }
    
    
}
```

StaffInformation.java

```
package com.webservices.Last;

import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class StaffInformation {
    
    @XmlElement
    private String name;
    @XmlElement
    private String surname;
    @XmlElement
    private String tcNo;

    
    
    
    public String getTcNo() {
        return tcNo;
    }
    public void setTcNo(String tcNo) {
        this.tcNo = tcNo;
    }
    public StaffInformation() {
        super();
    }
    public StaffInformation(String name, String surname, String tcNo) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.tcNo = tcNo;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }
    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: So, what does the log of tomcat say?

Answer (score 0):

you are hitting http://localhost:8080/Last/webapi/employee/p2 url

try with
http://localhost:8080/webapi/employee/p2
or
add '/last' in your web.xml, url pattern field

Answer (score 0):

The path you are requesting is not found by the server, hence you are seeing the 500 internal server error.
You have mentioned as @Path(value = "employee") for your main path whereas that should be

```
    @Path(value = "/employee")
```

and changing that to "**/employee**" should work fine. I tried your code in my local machine and it just worked fine after changing to "**/employee**".

This means the URL starts with /employee (after Application path) and remaining methods to follow this URL. Forex in your case http://localhost:8080/Last/webapi/employee/p2